# Oracle procedure/function to create a trigger in table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a procedure that given a table name, it will create a sequence and auto incrementing trigger, all using variables **based on the table name**.

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CREATE_SEQUENTIAL_TR(table_name VARCHAR)
is -- Tried using declare but it wouldn't accept
    coluna_cod varchar(100 char);
begin
    --Finding the cod column name for this table first
    --They start with "PK_CD"
    select 
        COLUMN_NAME 
    into
        coluna_cod
    from 
        ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
    where 
        TABLE_NAME=table_name 
        and COLUMN_NAME like "PK_CD%";
    --Creating the sequence obj
    drop sequence "cod" || table_name;
    create sequence "cod" || table_name;
    --Now creating the trigger
    create or replace trigger "cod" || table_name || "tr"           
    before 
        UPDATE or INSERT on table_name
    for each row
    declare
        cod number := coluna_cod;
        tr_name varchar(100 char) := "cod" || table_name
    begin
        if UPDATING then
            if :new.cod != :old.cod then
                :new.cod := :old.cod;
            end if;
        else -- inserting
            :new.cod := tr_name.nextval();
        end if; 
    end;
end;
```

The complexity of this ended up quite out of the scope of my knowledge.

At the moment it is giving an error on `drop sequence "cod" || table_name` (Unexpected DROP symbol found) but I'm sure I have made other errors.

Can someone help me figure this logic out?

Comment: You cannot execute DDL statements in a pl/sql block.  You either have to use execute immediate, or just write a script and run through sqlplus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put DDL statements (like `drop` or `create` or `alter`) directly inside a PL/SQL block. If you want to do DDL inside PL/SQL, you can do an `execute immediate`:

```
declare
begin
  drop sequence X; -- error
  execute immediate 'drop sequence X'; -- works fine 
end;
/
```